# pcap_open_offline(): overwrites or appends

Tags: file, pcap

ALL,

Unfortunately the documentation about the function found [here](https://www.tcpdump.org/manpages/pcap_open_offline.3pcap.html) does not specify the mode file is opened with.

Could someone please clarify.

TIA!!

Comment: Stack Overflow is not the appropriate venue for questions/bugs in tcpdump docs. It looks like tcpdump issues can be filed on the github repo (someone correct me if there's a better place): https://github.com/the-tcpdump-group/tcpdump.

Comment: @RossJacobs, I will, but in the meantime - do you know how this call operates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You meant `pcap_dump_open()`.
2. It overwrites; `pcap_dump_open_append()` appends.